# Spring Data MongoDB Date between two Dates

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

i'm using Spring Data for MongoDB and got the following classes

```
class A {
    List<B> b;
}

class B {
    Date startDate;
    Date endDate;
}
```

when i save an object of A it gets persisted like

```
{
    "_id" : "DQDVDE000VFP8E39",
    "b" : [
          {
              "startDate" : ISODate("2009-10-05T22:00:00Z"),
              "endDate" : ISODate("2009-10-29T23:00:00Z")
          },
          {
              "startDate" : ISODate("2009-11-01T23:00:00Z"),
              "endDate" : ISODate("2009-12-30T23:00:00Z")
          }
    ]
}
```

Now i want to query the db for documents matching entries in b where a given date is between startDate and endDate.

```
Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("b").elemMatch(
    Criteria.where("startDate").gte(date)
    .and("endDate").lte(date)
);
```

Which results in the following mongo query:

```
{
   "b": {
       "$elemMatch": { 
           "startDate" : { "$gte" : { "$date" : "2009-11-03T23:00:00.000Z"}}, 
           "endDate" : { "$lte" : { "$date" : "2009-11-03T23:00:00.000Z"}}
       }
   }
}
```

but returns no resulting documents. Does anybody know what i'm doing wrong? I don't get it...

Thank you very much in advance!!

Comment: What's `"margins"` doing in that mongo query?  Is that something specific to the Java driver?  I don't see that anywhere in your data.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't correspond to the Spring Data query, which is also incorrect.  You should be querying where("b"), not where("a").

Comment: Im sorry guys, it was late yesterday. I removed the two copy n paste errors!

Comment: The one document you show doesn't satisfy the query, are there others that do?  Should your `$gte` and `$lte` terms be swapped.

Comment: @sics, which version of the spring-data-mongodb are you using?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to find docs where `date` is between the `startDate` and `endDate` of a `b` array element then you need to reverse your `gte` and `lte` calls:

```
Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("b").elemMatch(
    Criteria.where("startDate").lte(date)
    .and("endDate").gte(date)
);
```

Comment: Oh my gosh, notice to brain: coding after 12 hours of work (also coding) is not good :) thank you for helping me out with this - beginner's mistake!

Comment: side question - how would you index with the `startDate` and `endDate` fields? My understanding is that, when indexing, the "range" field is positioned as last in the compound-index. Example: "Find all men with ages between 50 and 75". With `gender` and `age` fields, you'd make a compound index on `gender-age`. (http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/date_range/ 
)

Comment: Can we do that if those dates are in string form ?

Answer (score 1):

```
{"created_at":{$gt:ISODate("2013-04-30T00:00:00Z"),$lt:ISODate("2013-04-30T23:59:59Z")}}
```

Comment: While this is correct from a purely mongo standpoint the question was about spring-data-mongo's API